# Can you cast Thunderwave and then Misty Step on the same turn in that order?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

*Imra the wizard is cornered! Surrounded by multiple foes, she casts Thunderwave in an attempt to push her enemies back. One of them succeeds on the saving throw!*

Knowing that moving out of their range might trigger an attack of opportunity, can she cast *Misty Step* in the same turn?

I'm asking this because the rules under Casting a Spell states that

> A spell cast with a Bonus Action is especially swift. You must use a Bonus Action on Your Turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven’t already taken a Bonus Action this turn. You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a Casting Time of 1 action.

Does the order of spells casted matter? The wording makes it seem like you **can't** cast a Bonus Action spell and *then* an Action spell, but you **can** do it the other way around.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: @Someone_Evil yes, you are correct. I have been looking for the answer and google hasn't given me any, so this helps. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No need, dupe pointers are useful because others who search or would ask using the same words are more likely to find this instead of that one, but will then be directed where they need to go. Anecdotally, I found the target q through a dupe when searching. They are useful, though we get how that utility isn't necessarily obvious :)

Comment: I also added the comprehensive bonus action spell question as a dupe target.